# How to convert CString to Windows API and custom functions that use WCHAR?

Tags: c++, winapi, c-strings, wchar

So I have thousands of functions in my C++ code that take in as a parameter such as:

```
void SomeFunction(WCHAR *sSomeStringIn)
    {
    ...
    }
```

And within the function, it call Windows APIs such as:

```
GetWindowsText(...)
```

**How do I send a CString INTO my custom function**? Secondly, then convert the incoming WCHAR to a CString in SomeFunction so I can pass a WCHAR to GetWindowsText?

It is difficult doing calloc() and then free() everywhere and finding the leaks!

I'm looking for advice and best practice with existing WCHAR code and how to (slowly) convert to CString. I cannot rewrite hundreds of thousands of lines of code at once (obviously) to convert everything to CString.

Or...should I use another string-handling code besides CString?

Comment: *I cannot rewrite hundreds of thousands of lines of code at once* -- Then change one or two places to start with instead of the entire code base.  Second, I bet it is unlikely that you would have hundreds of thousands of lines of code to change in total.

Comment: Should I use another string-handling code besides CString?

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using different types of strings in a program, if unavoidable, write a wrapper to convert all the other string types to your default program string type, to avoid messing your codes.  For windows, you can stick to CString only. Try this helper functions:

```
CString convertToCString(WCHAR *sSomeStringIn)
{
    return CString(sSomeStringIn);
}

const WCHAR *convertTowchar(const CString& s)
{
    return  s.GetString();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WCHAR wch[10] = L"Hello";
    CString  s = convertToCString(wch);

    CString s2 = L"World";
    WCHAR wch2[10];
    wcscpy(wch2, convertTowchar(s2));
}
```

Comment: In `convertTowchar()`, you need to pass `s` by const reference (`const CString &s`). The current code is passing it by value, so it ends up returning a pointer to data that belongs to a temp copied `CString` that goes out of scope when `convertTowchar()` exits, freeing the data before the caller can ever use it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It should even be non-const reference so that the caller cannot use a temporary value and is forced to keep the string in a variable.

Comment: If I declare `CString s,`, does it go on the heap or stack?

Comment: CString stores on  the stack, so you don't need to delete at the end.

Answer (score 2):

`CString` by default is `WCHAR` compliant if your project is build with **Unicode Character Set**.
So, in order to call Windows API you need to do nothing, just pass `CString` as is. Because `CString` has built in `operator LPCWSTR`.

```cpp
CString str;
str = L"My message";
MessageBox(str);
```

For `GetWindowText`

```cpp
WCHAR buff[256];
GetWindowText(buff, 256);
CString str = buff;
```

or even like this:

```cpp
CString str;
str.Preallocate(256);
GetWindowText(str.GetBuffer(), 256);
```

Of course, if your project is build with **MBCS** (not unicode) you will have to constantly convert from `char*` to `WCHAR*` and back, which is a headache.

Comment: My projects are all 100% Unicode. I do have a few functions with MBCS requirements and conversions within the function.

Comment: Then you should not have any issues so far.